# Apache hive beeline error: JAVA Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again

Tags: hive, beeline

When I run the beeline command that came with Apache Hive 3.1.2 I get an error that says:

```
PS C:\Users\bluet> beeline.cmd
File Not Found
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hive/jdbc/JdbcUriParseException
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:650)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:632)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hive.jdbc.JdbcUriParseException
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:387)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
        ... 7 more
```

This is what the `beeline.cmd` command [looks like](https://pastebin.com/HKRuSCYu).

Hadoop is running smoothly including hdfs and yarn.

I am on Java 8.

What could be the problem?

Comment: I would focus on the first printed line that says some file isn't found. Did you set HIVE_HOME environment variable?

Comment: Ok thanks, I will try to figure that line out. Yes, I do have HIVE_HOME set to `$env:HIVE_HOME
D:\Hadoop\Hive\apache-hive-3.1.2-bin`

Comment: You shouldn't need `$env:HIVE_HOME` part of the value, but the error is likely part of the `set CLASSPATH` parts of the script

Answer (score 0):

I also received the same error. Then when i checked the file "**beeline.cmd**", i saw it needs **hive-jdbc-**-standalone.jar**. So Downloading that and placing it in **C:\Users-----\apache-hive-3.1.2-bin\lib** solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I meet the same problem and solved based on "**Akshay Katti**" reply.

My hive version is 2.3.9(apache-hive-2.3.9-bin).I found "hive-jdbc-2.3.9-standalone.jar" was under the "*apache-hive-2.3.9-bin/jdbc*" not "*apache-hive-2.3.9-bin/lib*".

So i copy it to path "*apache-hive-2.3.9-bin/lib*" then run beeline command successfully.